# How can I transform an expression with radicals to RootSum?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, polynomials

I am working with the integrals like these:

```
fun[q_] = (-1 + 2 wr2 - M1 Sin[(\[Pi] z)/2]^q + 
   2 M1 wr2 Sin[(\[Pi] zR)/2]^
    q)/((-1 + 2 wr2) (1 + M1 Sin[(\[Pi] z)/2]^q));
int2 = Integrate[fun[2], z, Assumptions -> {M1 > 0, 0 < zR < 1}]
int4 = Integrate[fun[4], z, Assumptions -> {M1 > 0, 0 < zR < 1}]
int8 = Integrate[fun[8], z, Assumptions -> {M1 > 0, 0 < zR < 1}]
```

Mathematica returns results of integration in terms of `RootSum` in all cases when `q>4` and I find it quite convenient. So my first question is:

**Can I cause `Integrate` to return result in terms of `RootSum` also for `q=4`?**

Or

**How can I transform an expression with radicals to `RootSum`?**

Note: Actually, I need definite integrals but Mathematica is not able to compute definite integral, e.g., in case of `q=8`.

My second question is related to specific form of `fun[q]`. In case of, e.g., `q=8` the integration yields

```
(1/(-1 + 
 2 wr2))(-z + (1/\[Pi])
  32 wr2 RootSum[
    M1 - 8 M1 #1 + 28 M1 #1^2 - 56 M1 #1^3 + 256 #1^4 + 70 M1 #1^4 - 
      56 M1 #1^5 + 28 M1 #1^6 - 8 M1 #1^7 + M1 #1^8 &, (
     2 ArcTan[Sin[\[Pi] z]/(Cos[\[Pi] z] - #1)] #1^3 - 
      I Log[1 - 2 Cos[\[Pi] z] #1 + #1^2] #1^3)/(-M1 + 7 M1 #1 - 
      21 M1 #1^2 + 128 #1^3 + 35 M1 #1^3 - 35 M1 #1^4 + 21 M1 #1^5 - 
      7 M1 #1^6 + M1 #1^7) &] (1 + M1 Sin[(\[Pi] zR)/2]^8))
```

Important feature of this expression is that the first argument of `RootSum` depends on parameter `M1` and is free of parameter `zR`. The first argument of `RootSum` is in fact specifies polynomial equation to be solved. Roots of this equation are to be put into the second argument of `RootSum` and the sum the obtained terms to be evaluated. I guess that in certain cases computations can be speed up it the previously computed roots are memorized. For example, if we draw the result of integration versus `zR` at fixed `M1`.

**I guess that it is possible to write a custom analog of `RootSum`, which could have ability to memorize the roots of the first argument, but  may be there is a more elegant way?**